# How to print log statements in a single line using Log4J?

Tags: java, log4j

I have a maven application which contains the logger configured as below.

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class StartCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ChunkRecon chRecon;
        Options options = new Options();
        Option input    = new Option("s", "ssn", true, "source system names");
        input.setRequired(false);
        options.addOption(input);
        CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
        HelpFormatter formatter  = new HelpFormatter();
        CommandLine cmd          = null;
        CustomSsnTableRecon cstr;
        final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(StartCount.class.getName());
        try {
            cmd = parser.parse(options, args);
            if(cmd.hasOption("s")) {            // Checks if there is an argument '--s' in the CLI.
                String sources = cmd.getOptionValue("s");
                if(sources == null) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a source system name using the option '--s' and submit the jar again.. Ex: --s ABC ");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                if(sources.contains("custom")) {
                    cstr = new CustomSsnTableRecon(sources);
                    cstr.getChunks();
                    cstr.reconDataFile();
                } else {
                    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Starting recon for the source: " + sources);
                    chRecon = new ChunkRecon(sources);
                    chRecon.getChunks();
                    chRecon.reconDataFile();
                }
            } else {
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Please enter a source system using the option '--s' and submit the jar again. Ex: --s ABC");
                System.out.println("Please enter a source system name using the option '--s' and submit the jar again.. Ex: --s ABC ");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        } catch(ParseException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Please enter a source system using the option '--s' and submit the jar again. Ex: --s ABC");
            formatter.printHelp("utility-name", options);
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my logger.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

When I run the program I don't see any errors and the logs are coming out fine. But they are being printed in two lines as shown below:

```
Nov 18, 2019 12:30:22 PM com.recordcount.entry.StartCount main
INFO: Starting recon for the source: GCORP_HFM
```

Project Structure:

[image]

Is there any way I can print the log in a single statement & also can we print just the class name instead of full package & class name:

```
Nov 18, 2019 12:30:22 PM StartCount main INFO: Starting recon for the source: GCORP_HFM
```

Comment: Your log4j is not picking up your `logger.properties` file. Your ConversionPattern does not match the printed lines at all (see the date: %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} should result in `2019-11-18 12:30:22`, not `Nov 18, 2019 12:30:22 PM`).
You probably should rename your properties file to `log4j.properties`, which is the default name for it.

Comment: I did rename it to Log4j Properties and it is still the same.

Comment: Looking at your project structure I noticed you have two `log4j.properties`. Why?

Comment: Oh yeah. I first created it outside the resource dir but realised it later on. Instead of drag and dropping it inside resources, I copy pasted it. I'll update the project structure now. But would that have an impact on the outcome?

Comment: That depends on how maven is packing your application, but if you haven't customised it, then the properties file outside of `resources` should be ignored afaik. Just thought it was worth it mentioning this.

Comment: Now regarding your question, the format that your logs are being printed is defined by the `ConversionPattern`. Something somewhere is defining this layout you're seeing, with 2 lines (it has a `%n` in the middle of the pattern).
You should investigate how your log4j is being configured. Also you should take into consideration how maven is packing your app (an easy way of checking this is unzipping the generated `war` or `jar` file and checking if its contents are where they were supposed to be - maybe in the generated jar/war your log4.properties is not in the right place?).

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the pattern of your logger with ConversionPatterns in the settings of Log4J: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html
This helps you achieve more customized log messages and you can experiment with what the options are and what you would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename your log properties file from 'logger.properties' to 'log4j.properties'.
2. To output only class name use `%C{1}` instead of `%c{1}`.